# Selecting all <div>s that have a <p> somewhere in them

Tags: css

Say I have:

```
<div class="thing">
    <a>hi</a>
    <span class="poo">
        <p id="hello">my name is</p>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="thing">
    <a>hi</a>
    <span class="poo">
        nothing to see here
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to select the first div, but only because it has a `p#hello` inside it.

Comment: With pure CSS I guess it is not possible, but let us keep the answers coming!

Answer (score 3):

With pure CSS it is not possible, you may try to use `Jquery` and try using [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

> The expression `$( "div:has(p)")` matches a `<div>` if a `<p>` exists
>   anywhere among its descendants, not just as a direct child.

Comment: OP never asked for jQuery solution

Comment: @Mr.Alien:- Did I missed something? I think that is a good way to proceed and it is not possible with pure CSS
:)

Comment: didn't down voted but yea, perhaps, cuz you provided a jQuery solution to the question where user didn't asked for jQuery solution :) am not saying your answer is wrong but it is irrelevant here unless he asks for js answers...

Comment: @Mr.Alien:- Got your point. Update my answer :)

Comment: Awesome, it answers my question, but it needs to be css because I'm making an adblock rule

Comment: @user104323:- It is not possible using pure CSS!

Comment: @user104323:- Not sure but are you trying to achieve something like this:- http://jsfiddle.net/AHHrF/82/